# Get Azure Credentials from VSTS Service Endpoint

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, devops

I want to write a custom tool to use inside VSTS to deploy service to Azure.
At the moment this is done using VSTS pipelines in UI and I want to replace it with a C# code.

If I look inside logs of the Azure Cli task there will bo something like this:

```
[command] az.cmd login --service-principal -u *** -p *** --tenant ***
```

And at the end of this step

```
az account clear
```

I want to reproduce this behaviour, read the credentials from the service endpoint. I already created the PAT just dont know how to use it properly...

Comment: If someone is trying to solve the same problem, I have a workaround - works for now. I created a variable group where saved those usernames and keys from azure. Had to create a new one and this feels a bit insecure... But works.

Comment: I think you can only do that when your code is running inside of a VSTS Task.Then you can let the user configure a Azure RM Subscription service and read from that. You can look how this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-azurergtag) does it by looking at the sourcecode [here](https://github.com/maikvandergaag/msft-vsts-extensions/tree/develop/extensions/azurergtag)

Comment: @RobBos thanks for the links! Not exactly what I am looking for, unfortunately...